# firestore is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to access to my db on firestore, I get this error: 
TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default.firestore is not a function

I don't understand why. On my "firebase.js" I wrote:

```
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const config = {
    apiKey: XXX,
    authDomain:XXX,
    databaseURL: XXX,
    projectId: XXX,
    storageBucket: XXX,
    messagingSenderId:XXX,
    appId: XXX"
}

class Firebase {
    constructor() {
        firebase.initializeApp(config)
        this.auth = firebase.auth()
        this.db = firebase.firestore()
    }


}

export default new Firebase()
```

The "auth" is working without any problems. But I get the error when I try to add something to the database, using this line:

`firebase.firestore().collection('datiutenti').add({ nome: "test"})`

or

`this.db.collection('datiutenti').add({nome: "test"})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because their is no method: `firebase.firestore()` as the method is: `firebase.firestore(APP)`

The way to initialize the db object in JS is with the following code:

```
         var config = {
            apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
            authDomain: "firestore-snippets.firebaseapp.com",
            projectId: "PROJECT_ID"
        };
        var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
        db = firebase.firestore(app);
```

for more reference you can check the code [here](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/cee9068490fbfb03c123fbda87bc08a73a122520/firestore/test.firestore.js) which is the official Github